# SQL query become extremely slower with top

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2016

```
select  * from RmiMember 
  WHERE  [LastName] like ('li%') AND [FirstName] like ('ma%') 
  ORDER BY FullName asc
```

0.3 Sec

This simple query takes 0.300 Sec to run but as soon as I add top 10 it becomes 3.0 Sec and If I change it to top 100 it takes 0.300 sec!

```
select top 10 * from RmiMember 
  WHERE  [LastName] like ('li%') AND [FirstName] like ('ma%') 
  ORDER BY FullName asc
```

3.0 Sec

Comment: Is there any index in your table?

Comment: What do the query plans look like?

Comment: For **what RDBMS** is this??

Comment: @D-Shih It does for FirstName and LastName

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Very simple query plan

Comment: @marc_s SQL server 2016 Std.